# How to copy RFF file into a table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I need to import .RFF file into a table in postgres with `|` as delimiter.

My code is

```
\copy my_table from 'C\\path\file.rrf' DELIMITR ('|')
```

It throws an error. Can you please advise me.

Comment: `It throws an error` What error? What are some (sample) contents of the file?

Comment: It throws 'extra data after last expected column ' . Sample data E1112|EX|K|OON|

Comment: I still get the error . can anyone help me ?